# How do I horizontally center this alert?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to display an alert when a user clicks a button but can't figure out how to horizontally center an alert. I'd like the alert to stay within #main. See [this fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/6epab/6/)

thanks!

Comment: Please don't post questions which contain nothing useful but a link to a jsfiddle. Your question needs to be self-contained and answerable without opening any links.

Comment: @RohitAzad His message box is overflowing, read the question..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your markup and CSS positioning is actually wrong, instead of using `position: fixed;` use `position: relative;` for `#main` and `position: absolute;` for `#message` and also shift your message `div` in `#main div`

And about the calculation part, when you want to center a `div`, you've to give `top: value (-)minus height` of the `div` to bring it vertically center..

[My Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6epab/9/)

Answer (score 4):

Make sure that #main has a `position` other than `static`, then assign the following rules to the alert:

```
position: absolute;
left: 50%;
top: 50%;
margin-left: -width;
margin-top: -height;
```

Replace `width` and `height` with the correct values.

Answer (score 3):

As the solution through css proposed by @Darkwater is correct, some time ago I created this plugin for jQuery, which still uses the CSS, so that it can be quickly reused on multiple objects.

Create a new method for jQuery called *`center`*:

```js
$.fn.center = function() {
    this.css("position","absolute").css("z-index","5000")
    .css("top","50%").css("left","50%")
    .css("margin",(-(this.height()/2))+"px 0 0 "+(-(this.width()/2))+"px"); 
    return this;
};
```

Then bind it to your object (your alert `div#message` in this case) just after the `.show()`:

```js
$("#message").show().center();
```

And the `div` will be centered both vertically and horizontally.

EDIT: remember to bind the method `center()` just after the method `show()` or similar that makes visible the element to the DOM, because, as far as I know, jQuery can't handle properly hidden elements.

Answer (score 2):

```
#message{
  display: none;
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  text-align: center;
}
```